# SQL alter number of filters in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

Sometimes I need to alter the number of filters in WHERE clause and I'm looking for suggestions to do it best. 
Here is a scenario:

Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
Col1 contains unique id.
Col2 contains numbers 0 thru 1000, non-unique.
Col3 contains letters of alphabet A thru Z, non-unique.

I have a StoredProc1 that takes only one argument but based on argument's value it should search either Col2 only or both Col2 and Col3. The decision to look at 1 or 2 columns would be arbitrary and the stored procedure needs to be optimized for performance.

Code below is doing the job but is extremely hard to manage. I have a stored procedure that contains 128 different branches this way and if I add one more condition it will constitute another 128 branches and total of 6000 lines of code. There must be a better way.

I was thinking about declaring another variable and setting it to a default value that would always be a no-match. Then based on the value passed in the StoredProc1 parameter, set the second variable to a relevant value. The problem with this solution is that it would decrease performance of searches where the second filter is not applicable.
I can't alter StoredProc1 definition because it is called by countless other processes.
So far the only thing that comes to my mind is to create another SP and call it from the main one if the condition is true and keep current proc as else branch.

```
StoredProc1 ( @filter ) as
begin
    if (@filter = 1)
    begin
        select col1, col2, col3
        from Table1
        where Col2 = @filter or Col2 = 'A'
    end
    else
    begin
        select Col1, Col2, Col3
        from Table1
        where Col2 = @Filter
    end
end
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is your friend

Comment: Please provide full list of input parameters. For example Col1FilterPresent, Col1FilterPresent, ... Col1FulterValue ... . I think that there is a way (not sure though), but I need input parameters. Also you need filters as AND or as OR?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: is @filter an integer or a varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StoredProc1
@filter DataType
as
begin
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'select Col1, Col2, Col3 
           from Table1 WHERE 1 = 1 '
          + CASE WHEN   @filter = 1 THEN N' AND Col2 = @Param or Col2 = ''A''' 
            ELSE N' AND Col2 = @Filter' END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql 
                     , N'DECLARE @Param DataType'
                     , @Param = @filter
end
```

Your can have multiple Case statement to check against multiple Parameters and built you sql string.
Much more flexible and secure way of doing this kind of operations.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know if you could plug CASE in WHERE clause. Do you expect high performace penalty for this option?

Comment: @user2611947 - The CASE statement is not part if the Where clause in the resulting sql statement, but only in the string concatenation to build the value for this one variable. Building the sql statement string will be the least of your performance worries.

Comment: @user2611947 you may want to do some research regarding the caching of execution plans and sp_executesql.  It does *sometimes*.  If the query had to compiled each time, then you're losing the reason for making it a proc.

Answer (score 2):

```
StoredProc1 ( @filter ) as
begin
  select col1, col2, col3
  from Table1
  where Col2 = @filter or (@filter = '1' and Col2 = 'A')
end
```

You're going to lose performance no matter what solution you're choosing.  Dynamic SQL will potentially need to be compiled every time.  Your "branch" method works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can have something like:

```
declare @iFilterCol1 int;
declare @iFilterCol2 int;
declare @iFilterCol3 varchar(100);

set @iFilterCol1 = 5;
set @iFilterCol2 = 100;
set @iFilterCol3 = 'aaa';

select col1, col2, col3
from Table1
where 
    (Col1 = case when @iFilterCol1 is not null then @iFilterCol1 else Col1 end) 
    and (Col2 = case when @iFilterCol2 is not null then @iFilterCol2 else Col2 end) 
    and (Col3 = case when @iFilterCol3 is not null then @iFilterCol3 else Col3 end);
```

In this case when you assign value to @iFilterCol1 you will filter by Col1, otherwise you will skip it. The same with other 2 columns. Take into account that I use `AND`. Yuo can use `OR` instead, but combination of both depends of the filter that you want to apply and in some cases will not be possible.